# Nifi denormalize json message and storing in Hive

Tags: apache-nifi

I am consuming a nested Json *Kafka* message and after some transformations, storing it into hive.

Requirement is json contains several nested arrays and we have to denormalize it so that each element in array forms a separate row in hive table. Would *JoltTransform* or *SplitJson* work or do I need to write groovy script for the same?

Sample input - 
`{"TxnMessage": {"HeaderData": {"EventCatg": "F"},"PostInrlTxn": {"Key": {"Acnt": "1234567890","Date": "20181018"},"Id": "3456","AdDa": {"Area": [{"HgmId": "","HntAm": 0},{"HgmId": "","HntAm": 0}]},"escTx": "Reload","seTb": {"seEnt": [{"seId": "CAKE","rCd": 678},{"seId": "","rCd": 0}]},"Bal": 6766}}}`

Expected Output - `{"TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.AdDa.Area.HgmId":"","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.AdDa.Area.HntAm":0,"TxnMessage.HeaderData.EventCatg":"F","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Key.Acnt":"1234567890","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Key.Date":"20181018","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Id":"3456","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.escTx":"Reload","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Bal":6766}
{"TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.AdDa.Area.HgmId":"","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.AdDa.Area.HntAm":0,"TxnMessage.HeaderData.EventCatg":"F","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Key.Acnt":"1234567890","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Key.Date":"20181018","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Id":"3456","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.escTx":"Reload","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Bal":6766}
{"TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.seTb.seEnt.seId":"CAKE","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.seTb.seEnt.rCd":678,"TxnMessage.HeaderData.EventCatg":"F","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Key.Acnt":"1234567890","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Key.Date":"20181018","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Id":"3456","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.escTx":"Reload","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Bal":6766}
{"TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.seTb.seEnt.seId":"","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.seTb.seEnt.rCd":0,"TxnMessage.HeaderData.EventCatg":"F","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Key.Acnt":"1234567890","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Key.Date":"20181018","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Id":"3456","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.escTx":"Reload","TxnMessage.PostInrlTxn.Bal":6766}`

Comment: May want to try FlattenJson - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FlattenJson/index.html

Comment: FlattenJson is creating a single json output with array elements having indexes like [0],[1]